# Boiling water reactor

Tags: nuclear-physics, power, nuclear-engineering

What are the typical power densities in conventional boiling water nuclear reactor per cubic centimeter of fission material?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without going into the details of it, a conventional BWR gives a power density of $50 kW/liter$ inside the core, which is about half that of PWR.

Mind you, this includes the coolant inside the core and not the fissile material only. [ref](http://www.ati.ac.at/fileadmin/files/research_areas/ssnm/nmkt/06_BWR.pdf)